# Variable Defined in Switch Statement is Undefined in Rest of Function

Tags: jquery

for some reason my function gives me an undefined error in console. Why is this? The if and else statements are irrelevant in functionality; the sole issue is that "i" is never defined despite the fact that they are explicitly defined in the switch statement.

```
  $('#nav-em-search, #nav-un-search, #nav-db-search').click(function() {
    switch (this) {
        case '#nav-em-search':
            var i = document.getElementById('em-search');
            break;
        case '#nav-un-search':
            var i = document.getElementById('un-search');
            break;
        case '#nav-db-search':
            var i = document.getElementById('db-search');
            break;
    }
    if (!$('.searchbox').not(i).css('left','-60' + '%')) {
        $('.searchbox').not(i).animate({left:'-60' + '%'},500);
        setTimeout("$(this).animate({left:'25' + '%'},500)",500);
    } else {
        $(i).animate({left:'25' + '%'},500);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Log the variable `i` to check that it's not null

Answer (score 0):

`this` is set to the element that is clicked, not the ID of the element.
You can switch on `this.id` and remove the `#` before your cases, and it should work as intended.

```
  switch (this.id) {
    case 'nav-em-search':
      var i = document.getElementById('em-search');
      break;
    case 'nav-un-search':
      var i = document.getElementById('un-search');
      break;
    case 'nav-db-search':
      var i = document.getElementById('db-search');
      break;
  }
```